# How do I know which delimiter has occurred first using awk in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

How to know which delimiter has occurred first using single `awk` line.

Assume I have a file having contents:

```
AB BC DE
BC DE AB
DE BC AB
```

And I want to know which of the three `DE`,`AB`,`BC` has occurred first in each line.

I thought that I could use delimiter `BC` then take its first field and then `BC` and then take the first field of `AB`.

This can be done by:

```
$ awk -F'AB' '{print $1}' <file>   \
  | awk -F'BC' '{print $1}' <file> \
  | awk -F'DE' '{print $1}' <file>
```

However, is there any other way in which I can dynamically change delimiter inside awk line and get the above thing done using awk only once?

Edit:
Corrected the mistakes done earlier.

Comment: I’m struggling to understand what you’re trying to do. Firstly, does the input file have a single line as shown, or multiple lines. Also, any other pairs of letters?

Comment: I guess you call those letter pairs as **delimeters** -- really bizarre.

Comment: Side-note: `[BC]` does not mean `BC`. It means `B` or `C`. Use `-F'BC'` if you want to use `BC` as the delimiter.

Comment: @Guy Input can be multiline as well as can have characters other than the delimeters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, if your file only contains the combinations `AB`,`BC` or `DE` in combination with `newline`, then the answer is straightforward :

```
awk '{print $1}' file
```

This is conform your example. Nonetheless, I do not believe this is the case.
It stands to reason that the solution of [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48487283/8344060) is clearly the way to forward! It is clean, simple and on top of that a one-liner.

However, from a pure educational perspective, a different `awk` approach is presented here.

If you want to find the "first" separator in a line, you could attack the problem from a different angle. Instead of interpreting the line as a set of columns, you could understand it as a set of records. This brings the question to "which record separator has been found first :

> **`RT` (gawk extention)**
>   The input text that matched the text denoted by `RS`, the record
>   separator. It is set every time a record is read.

For a single line of characters, you could do something like this :

```
$ echo "AB BC DE BC DE AB DE BC AB" \
   | awk 'BEGIN{RS="DE|AB|BC"}{print RT;exit }' 
AB
```

Now it is possible to play with the idea a bit more. Constantly toggle the `RS` between a newline and the requested set. This is just to show how flexible `awk` is.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RSSET="DE|AB|BC";RS=RSSET}
       (RS=="\n"){RS=RSSET;next}
       {print RT; RS="\n"; next}' file
```

If file is

```
AB BC DE BC DE AB DE BC AB
BC DE AB DE BC AB
DE AB DE BC AB
```

it outputs

```
AB
BC
DE
```

Comment: That will print the first "separator" in the input, not the first separator on each line of input. It'll also print a blank line if no separator exists in the input.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks, I have updated the answer a bit, to work with the same idea. But it stands to reason that your answer is the answer.

Answer (score 6):

If this isn't what you want:

```
awk 'match($0,/AB|BC|DE/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' file
```

then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

A `sed` solution, as it was tagged. The greedy nature of `sed` made this a tad more confusing, but I think the following works.

```
#!/usr/bin/sed -rnf

# This presumes you only want to print matching rows.
/(AB|CD|EF)/ {
    # add a line number
    =;
    # find first match, then remove rest of line
    s/(AB|CD|EF).*$/\1/;
    # this only leaves one possible match, so the greedy match all 
    # at the start doesnt match what we want.
    s/^.*(AB|CD|EF)/\1/; 
    # so print.
    p 
}
```

And for an example, I've changed the 'codes' to check it was the first being matched:

```
~$> printf "%b\n" "$letters"
ABa BBa ABb BBb ABc BBc
BBc ABc BBb ABb BBa ABa
ABb ABc BBa BBc
not right

~$> echo "$letters" | sed -rn '/(AB.|BB.)/ {=; s/(AB.|BB.).*$/\1/; s/^.*(AB.|BB.)/ \1/; p }'
1
 ABa
2
 BBc
3
 ABb
```